# Server-Sent Events does not work on Nexus 7 webview with Android version 4.3

Tags: google-chrome, webview, server-sent-events

I'm now using Nexus 7 for my project which is using Server-Sent Events to get alert message.

On Nexus 7 Chrome browser, it works well.
But when I load the same page using webview, it does not work (saying "your browser does not support server-sent events...").

The source codes are exactly the same as [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp].

I think there maybe some difference between Chrome browser and Android Webview.
Could some one tell me how to make it work using Android Webview?

Answer (score 0):

I think WebChromeClient is the one you need anyway. I am using both WebViewClient **AND** WebChromeClient because the latter one is full HTML5 enabled.

So in your Android WebView you can use **BOTH** Clients at the same time.

For instance

```
// clients
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(this));
webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this));
```

I use WebChromeClient for all the fancy stuff, like Javascript popups and yes, SSE using PHP scripts.

Comment: Could you please give me a sample on how to set CustomWebChromeClient? I'm not sure which method I should override to implement SSE. Thanks!

Comment: I am not using SSE in android. instead I use javascript inside the webpage to handle SSE. That webpage is served in the WebClients.

Comment: oh I forgot to mention, SSE crashed the WebClient.. Signal 11 on the WebViewCoreThread, so be careful with this

Comment: Thank you Coen! So now you're using ajax? I'm thinking about changing to another way instead of SSE...